# How to merge different node modules and make different bundles from them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

**Description:** Say I have 7 dependencies as below

```
"dependencies": {
  "control-module-one": "1.00",
  "control-module-two": "1.00",
  "control-module-three": "1.00",
  "react": "16.9.0",
  "react-dom": "16.9.0",
  "utility-module-one": "2.00",
  "utility-module-two": "2.00"
}
```

**Challenge:** I want to merge modules group wise and make different bundles group wise as well. So it could be like below

```
dist>
  control-module-bundle.js
  react-module-bundle.js
  utility-module-bundle.js
```

**What I tried?**

I tried "splitChunks" and "cacheGroups" in webpack, but it is bundling all the modules in different files.

**Query:** Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done using 'splitChunks' of Webpack-4.

```
splitChunks: {
 cacheGroups: {
  control_module_group: {
   test: /[\\/]node-modules[\\/]control/,
   name: 'control-module-bundle',
   chunks: 'all'
  }
 }
}
```